# How I Disabled Swagger-UI in Production in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have an Spring Boot REST API application and I integrated Swagger for documentation and also using it to test API's with Swagger-UI.

Now my task was to disable the Swagger-UI on our production environtment (public domain) and enable it in our dev environment which was on private IP.

Answer (score 2):

With Swagger vr-3.0.0 we can add **springfox.documentation.enabled**=false/true in corresponding environment profile application.properties file.

Like for prod server **application-prod.properties** file

```
springfox.documentation.enabled=false
```

And for dev server **application-dev.properties** file

```
springfox.documentation.enabled=true
```

And run the app, by specifing the profile in VM arguments

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod/dev
```

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve it, I did the below mentioned changes in my Swagger Config class and in application.properties file.

My pom.xml, where I added the below dependencies to integrate swagger.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my **application-dev.properties** file, I added one key-value pair with boolean value-true

```
use-swagger=true
```

and in my **application-prod.properties** file, I changed the value to false

```
use-swagger=false
```

Now, finally in my SwaggerConfig class, I used the above key to enable/disable my Swagger-UI

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig  implements EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.jkoder.example.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .enable(Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty("use-swagger")));
    }


    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```

**enable(Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty("use-swagger")))**
this function lets you enable or disable the swagger-ui in the required environment.

To execute the Spring Boot REST Api application, we were using the below commands

In Dev environment-

```
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev target/myapp-1.0.jar &
```

In Production environment-

```
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod target/myapp-1.0.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

Just annotate your configuration with @Profile annotation

```
@Profile({"local", "dev"})
```